# Django DRF Getting Missing Auth Headers with JWT, but With Permission and Auth on ReadOnly Views

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt

I'm working with both the latest Django 3.0.2 and DRF 3.11.0 using djangorestframework-simplejwt 4.4.0. I did not have this problem before on a previous Django 2.2.0 project (and older lib versions), but I cannot figure out why I cannot access a view with readonly permissions set and default authentication looks okay in settings. For the simplejwt and firebaseauth library, I'm using the default settings (with correct credentials for firebaseauth, verified it works fine).

If I specify the authentication_classes as empty in the view, then it works fine, but this is just an example. I expected the defaults to work, from settings: unless I'm incorrect and should be explicitly set this way. I have also tried using gunicorn and waitress-serve, and it's the same result.

Here is the view:

```
class NoteList(generics.ListAPIView):
"""
List all Notes. Not used
"""
# authentication_classes = []
permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
serializer_class = NoteSerializer

def get_queryset(self):
    notes = Note.objects.all()
    return notes
```

Here is my settings:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware', ]


REST_FRAMEWORK = {
# When you enable API versioning, the request.version attribute will contain a string
# that corresponds to the version requested in the incoming client request.
'DEFAULT_VERSIONING_CLASS': 'rest_framework.versioning.NamespaceVersioning',

# Authentication settings
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
    'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    'drf_firebase_auth.authentication.FirebaseAuthentication',
],

# Permission settings
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
    'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly',
    'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    'rest_framework.permissions.IsAdminUser',
    'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly',
],

# For unit test cases
'TEST_REQUEST_DEFAULT_FORMAT': 'json',

# Pagination
'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.LimitOffsetPagination',
'PAGE_SIZE': 50,
```

}

If ordering the above matters, what is the correct order to have them in?

Urls, if it matters:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('anotes/', NoteList.as_view(), name="lame-notes"),
```

]

Now, when I visit the URL anonymously, I always get:

```
GET /v1/anotes/

HTTP 401 Unauthorized
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="api"

{
    "detail": "Invalid Authorization header format, expecting: JWT <token>."
```

I've been stuck on this issue for a while and could not find any similar problems to solve it. On my older Django project, I don't get this 401 Unauthorized and am able to have ReadOnly work correctly.
The view or endpoint only works correctly if I'm logged in.

If I'm missing any information please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Permissions in REST framework are always defined as a list of permission classes.
Before running the main body of the view each permission in the list is checked. If any permission check fails an exceptions.PermissionDenied or exceptions.NotAuthenticated exception will be raised, and the main body of the view will not run.
So an anonymous user can check the first item in your permission list, but fails at second. You should decide what will your default behavior will be and keep that in the list.

Comment: I see and it is the same with authentication correct? But in authentication, if one fails, I thought it goes to the next auth library to try. If the first one fails, it just fails the whole middleware for authentication?

Comment: @Roys The permission check happens in ***logical AND*** fashion and authentication happen in ***logical OR*** fashion, which means, if the first authentication scheme fail to identify the incoming request, DRF tries the second auth scheme and so on.

Comment: @ArakkalAbu oh that makes sense, I will change my permissions (as you see in the settings, it would fail) and try it today, thank you for the clarification sir.